# Converting from SAFE (Sentinel-1) to BEAM-DIMAP?

Tags: metadata, gdal-translate, raster-conversion, sentinel-1, sentinel-snap

I need to convert Sentinel-1 data from the SAFE format (used by the ESA's Sentinel project) to the BEAM-DIMAP format.

I know that GDAL can convert GeoTIFF files (which are used by Sentinel-1) into ENVI, but it adds an XML file containing some metadata the .img and .hdr files. From [this link](http://www.harrisgeospatial.com/docs/ENVIHeaderFiles.html), I understand that the Coordinate Reference System should be in the header file which is not the case using GDAL.

I've also tried to use SNAP, the Sentinel software, to export SAFE to BEAM-DIMAP but there seems to be a loss of data as I can't retrieve the CRS.

Does someone know how to perform the conversion without any loss?

Ideally, I'd like something like SNAP where I give the whole SAFE directory as input and it outputs the .dim file and the .data directory of the BEAM-DIMAP format and doesn't require to do the conversion by hand.

Comment: I think ESA uses `.jp2` format for Sentinel-2, which at least can be read and geoereferenced by QGIS and therefore most probably by GDAL. So you could try to use [gdal_translate](http://www.gdal.org/gdal_translate.html) with `-of DIMAP` (although I'm, not sure if this is the same format as BEAM-DIMAP, maybe check [here](http://www.gdal.org/formats_list.html) for possible values of `-of`). Another solution would be to write something that reads the metadata, georeferences and converts the files step by step

Comment: @s6hebern Thanks for your answer. Sorry I forgot to mention that I'm working with Sentinel-1 data, hence the GeoTIFF format. I edited my question. I also know that I could use `gdal_translate` to convert images and then write a code to parse the metada but it would be cumbersome and I'd liek to know if there already exists something that could do ths for me.

Comment: do you work with SLC or GRD ? did you open your data by selecting the xml in the SAFE directory or a specific tile ?

Comment: @radouxju I tried with both SLC and GRD. I'm not sure what you mean but I opened the data in SNAP directly with the zip file I downloaded and I tried running `gdal_translate` on the GeoTIFF files.